# Unexpected token case number in custom lookup

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Built custom lookup referring below:

http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/07/17/re-usable-custom-lookup/

Lookup  field in Lightning components:

```
  public static List < sObject > fetchLookUpValues(String searchKeyWord, String ObjectName) {
    system.debug('ObjectName-->' + ObjectName);
    String searchKey = searchKeyWord + '%';
    List < sObject > returnList = new List < sObject > ();
    // Create a Dynamic SOQL Query For Fetch Record List with LIMIT 5  
    string sQuery = '';
    if(ObjectName == 'Queue'){
        sQuery = 'select Id,Name from Group where Type = \'Queue\' AND Name LIKE: searchKey order by createdDate DESC limit 5';  
    } 
    else if(ObjectName == 'Case'){

       sQuery =  'select id, CaseNumber from ' +ObjectName + 'where CaseNumber LIKE: searchKey order by createdDate DESC limit 5';   
    }
    else{
        sQuery =  'select id, Name from ' +ObjectName + ' where Name LIKE: searchKey order by createdDate DESC limit 5';    
    }

    List < sObject > lstOfRecords = Database.query(sQuery);
    for (sObject obj: lstOfRecords) {
        returnList.add(obj);
    }
    return returnList;
}
```

for queue and other objects it working properly. But Especially in case of case lookup that case field doesnt contain name field. so I used casenumber field for that

```
   sQuery =  'select id, CaseNumber from ' +ObjectName + 'where CaseNumber LIKE: searchKey order by createdDate DESC limit 5';
```

recieving below error:Unexpected token case Number

I belive case lookup should show case number(Autonumber).whats the best way to do that

But If I search it right it will not show any number in drop down:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This component assumes that the field returned is always Name. Since CaseNumber is different, we need to account for that in the JavaScript:

```
// We map CaseNumber to Name if present.
storeResponse.forEach(item => item.Name = item.Name || item.CaseNumber);
component.set("v.listOfSearchRecords", storeResponse);
```

Adding that one line of code should fix the display issue.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your else if block. You just need to add one more space before where keyword and your query will work fine.

```
    else if(ObjectName == 'Case'){

           sQuery =  'select id, CaseNumber from ' +ObjectName + ' where CaseNumber LIKE: searchKey order by createdDate DESC limit 5';   
        }
```

Comment: Okay.but If I search for number it will not display any mathching numbers in drop down